# Recursive function that returns multable array and a list

Tags: haskell, monads, composition, st-monad

I'm trying to build a recursive function, which for simplicity's sake, lets say it takes an list and builds an array and a list. Because I need to both read and write the array as it's being built, I'm using a mutable array so I can do constant time reads and writes. So the signature and function looks something like as follows:

```
f :: [a] -> ST s ([a], STArray s Int a) -> ST s ([a], STArray s Int a)
f (x:xs) curr_arr = 
  case blah of
    ... -> f xs new_arr
f [] curr_arr = curr_arr
```

I want a function `h` with the following signature:

```
h :: Int -> Int -> a -> [a] -> (Array Int a, [a])
```

And I want it to have the roughly following implementation:

```
h lbound ubound default_a xs = g (f xs (newArray lbound ubound default_a))
```

Problem is, I need a function `g` with this signature:

```
ST s ([a], STArray s Int a) -> (Array Int a, [a])
```

but I can't seem to hack together `runST` and `runSTArray` to achieve this.

Is there anyway to implement `g`, or should I make the signature of `f` completely different in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Monad` instance of `ST s` to implement the recursive calls to `f` (and the composition of their results): change `f`'s type to

```
f :: [a] -> ([a], STArray s Int a) -> ST s ([a], STArray s Int a)
```

which means the recursive calls in `f` will look something like

```
f xs curr = do
    xs' <- ...
    curr' <- ...
    next <- f xs' curr'
    combine curr next
```

and then `runST` it to completion in `h` (`runSTArray` doesn't work directly here, because you also have your `[a]` on the side):

```
h lo hi x0 xs = runST $ do
    curr <- newArray lo hi x0
    (ys, mArr) <- f xs (xs, curr)
    arr <- freeze mArr
    return (ys, arr)
```

This works because in that last expression, `ys :: [a]` and `arr :: Array Int a`, so neither depends on the choice of `s`.